# Store Google Places Data

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

We are using Google places API for searching nearby places and we are saving users review against every place in our database for that purpose we need to store some information of place in our database so that we can link those information with Google places API, but as we go through term of use we have found that no one is allowed to store any information of Google places in personal Database.

My question is that can we save Google place ID or just latitude and longitude for mapping purpose?

Is it acceptable by Google Inc.

Or what else I can do to link information from my database with places returned from Google Places API.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [reference property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details), at one point that didn't persist across sessions, but now it just says, it can always be used, but might not be the same.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult

> reference | string | An opaque string that may be used to retrieve up-to-date information about this Place (via 
>   (via PlacesService.getDetails()). reference contains a unique token that you can use
>   to retrieve additional information about this Place in a Place Details
>   request. You can store this token and use it at any time in future to
>   refresh cached data about this Place, but the same token is not
>   guaranteed to be returned for any given Place across different
>   searches.ference contains a unique token that you can use to retrieve
>   additional information about this Place in a Place Details request.
>   You can store this token and use it at any time in future to refresh
>   cached data about this Place, but the same token is not guaranteed to
>   be returned for any given Place across different searches.